# Excel : How to write everything I want on a single array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

On Excel, I have a table with many numeric results on B column obtained by a array formula.

For example:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 | EUA        |     12      |
| 2 | China      |     5       |
| 3 | Russia     |     8       |
| 4 |  ...       |     ...     |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

The array formula on B1 is just:

```
{=SUM(calculations using A1 and other table)}
```

Real formula on B1:

```
{=SUM(((LEN(Table[Origem])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Table[Origem];A1;"")))/LEN(A1))*((LEN(Table[Gênero])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Table[Gênero];$D$1;"")))/LEN($D$1)))}
```

That's an intermediate table that isn't necessary, because the raw data is on other table. I just need its results to use on other formula.

I'm only interessed in the country with the biggest value, in that case the EUA with B1 = 12. So I use this formula on C1 to get it:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3;MATCH(LARGE(B1:B3;1);B1:B3))
```

Result on C1: EUA

How can I write a formula to get the result of C1 without writhing all the formulas in the B column? Is it possible? I'm not interessed in the B column results.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you actually need a formula, but if you just care about the result, I would suggest using a pivot table. It's possible to display only the top X values, and since your raw data is located in a table, that's very convenient (provided your raw data is pivot table friendly). Here is [a tutorial that explains how to do it](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/top10_2010.php).

Comment: Thanks piko, but I think my raw data is not pivot table friendly. Some rows have multiple countries (example: "EUA/China"). If I use pivot table, the "EUA/China" row don't count as EUA or China. That's why I use the formula em B1 to count each time a country is found. Any tips?

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's not possible to drop the intermediary calculations without a pivot table, due to the specificity of your data ("EUA/China").

Comment: BTW, it reminded me of an example I provided on a previous answer. You might want to take a look at it. I used a `SUMPRODUCT` with partial text search, without the need of an array formula. It seems a bit more simple that your formula in B1, and has the advantage to also work with multiples criteria if you ever need it. Perhaps that will help! Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSECs.jpg

Comment: will `=index(A:A,match(max(B:B),B:B,0)` do?